# JS как дописать условие к задаче?

Tags: javascript

Условия задачи:

- Номер вмещает в себя 8мест+ можно 1 малыш.
- Должен быть 1 взрослый.
- На одного взрослого не может быть больше двух детей.

Я написал:

```
function canTheyBook(adultsCount=0, childrenCount=0, babiesCount=0) {
  if (adultsCount>=1 && adultsCount+childrenCount+babiesCount<=8 && childrenCount+babiesCount<=adultsCount*2 )  return true
  else return false;
}
```

Я не знаю, как указать условие для девятого малыша
`adults+children<=8 && babies<=1` нельзя, т.к. в тех восьми тоже могут быть малыши.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте сначала отсеять провальные варианты один за другим:

```js
function canTheyBook(adultsCount = 0, childrenCount = 0, babiesCount = 0) {
  const all = adultsCount + childrenCount + babiesCount;

  if (all > 9) return false;
  if (adultsCount === 0) return false;
  if (all === 9 && babiesCount === 0) return false;
  if (adultsCount * 2 < childrenCount + babiesCount) return false;

  return true;
}

console.log(canTheyBook(5, 4 , 1));
console.log(canTheyBook(0, 4 , 4));
console.log(canTheyBook(5, 4 , 0));
console.log(canTheyBook(1, 4 , 0));
console.log(canTheyBook(5, 3 , 1));
```